# How many ways can you arrange $n$ indistinguishable objects in $k$ distinguishable positions? (with $n\le k$)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

For example, if I wanted to know the ways of arranging two $1's$ in three positions, the answer is $3$ (in this case, $n=2, k=3$): $$11\_, 1\_1, \_11$$

Or if I wanted to know the number of ways of arranging four $1's$ in four positions the answer is one (in this case, $n=4, k=4$): $$1111$$

I think I have the formula, but I would like verification. Clearly, if $n=k$, the answer is $1$, and if $k-n=1$, the answer is $k$. If $k-n=p$, then we must have $p$ spaces in the final combination. We have $k$ options for the first space, then $k-1$ options for the second space, ..., and finally $k-p$ options for the $p$th space. Thus, there are $\frac{k!}{p!}= \frac{k!}{(n-k)!}$ possible combinations.

Comment: Can a position receive several objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry.
First of all, you should have $(k-n)!$ instead of $(n-k)!$, as we might have $n-k < 0$ and your argumentation is for $p = k-n$. Now trying this out with $k-n = 1$, we don't get $k$ but rather $k!$, showing us that your formula is wrong.

Now on to the right formula: We have $k$ positions and want to put $n$ objects. As the objects are indistinguishable, we only need to choose the positions. For that, we have
$${k \choose n}$$
choices, as you are hopefully already aware of (if not read at the beginning of the chapter, that is usually one of the first results).

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is almost correct, but you are not using the indistinguishability of the ones, so that you lack a $n!$ factor.

Basically you are dealing with words made of two symbols: the ones and the spaces, and you want to count the possible words made of $n$ ones and $n-k$ spaces. This number is then classicaly $${k-n \choose n} = {k \choose n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply collecting  $n$ objects from $k$ object i.e ${{n}\choose{k}}$

Comment: Is $N$ the same thing as $n$?

Comment: I have edited the problem